# Converting octave code to js without having to rewrite everything

Tags: javascript, octave

I have coded some octave code and have been thinking of turning it into JS so that I will be able to run it on a website. How would this be able to be done without having to completely rewrite the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a tool like [matscript](https://github.com/tobwin/matscript) or just make a server side solution